# Highlighting based on URL

Tags: jquery, url, tags, indexof

So I am trying to add a class to an li, based on the the URL matching the href of an a tag within the li.  My current code is adding a class to every li, but I need to try and get it to only add to the li that contains the matching a tag.  Does that make any sense? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
<div id="admin-action-menu" class="links">
<div id="cat_settings" class="cat_menu row-fluid">
    <ul   role="menu" >
        <? if (($user->type_id == 1) || ($user->type_id == 2)) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="icon system-settings">
                </div>
                <div class="action-text">
                    <span>
                        System Settings
                    </span>
                </div>
                <a href="/admin/system_settings"></a>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
        <? if (($user->type_id == 1) || ($user->type_id == 2)) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="icon email-settings">
                </div>
                <div class="action-text">
                    <span>
                        Email Settings
                    </span>
                </div>
                <a href="/admin/email_settings"></a>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="cat_people" class="cat_menu row-fluid">
    <ul  role="menu" >
        <? if ($user->type_id == 1) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="icon system-admins">
                </div>
                <div class="action-text">
                    <span>
                        System Admins
                    </span>
                </div>
                <a href="/admin/admin_list"></a>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
        <? if ($user->type_id == 1 || $user->type_id == 2) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="icon company-admins">
                </div>
                <div class="action-text">
                    <span>
                        Company Admins
                    </span>
                </div>
                <a href="/admin/company_admin_list"></a>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>


<script>

$('.cat_menu li').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).data('href');
    var url = window.location.href;

    if ( link = url ) {
    $(this).addClass('yuuuuup');
    } else {
    $(this).addClass('nooooope');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended to use a == here

```
if ( link = url ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of things wrong here. First, you are using `$(this).data('href');` to retrieve the href of the anchor tag within the li. Unless you left out relevant code, that will not work based on what you have posted. Instead (again based on what you have), to get the URL, do this:

```
var link = $('a', $(this)).attr('href');  //Assumes only one anchor is contained within the li
```

Then, with the way you've written this code, you need to check if the current iteration's href is contained in the current page's URL. You could do something like this:

```
if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf(link.toLowerCase()) != -1){
    $(this).addClass('yuuuuup'); // Match
} else {
    $(this).addClass('nooooope');  //No match
}
```

You can of course modify the code to see if the URLS match, and there are multiple ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. But those were the two big things that were wrong.